# Does the C++ standard library have UTF-8 functions?

Tags: c++, string, utf-8

I can create a UTF-8 string in C++ like this:

```
char str[] = u8"a UTF-8 string literal";
```

But does the C++ standard library have UTF-8 functions? for example, does it have a function to get the number of characters that a UTF-8 string have?

Comment: "*the number of characters that a UTF-8 string have?*" This is not a question you should ask, since it's too non-specific to be useful. That is, do you mean "codepoints", "grapheme-clusters", or something else?

Comment: "Get the number of characters" is much more difficult (and much less useful) than you think. For example, how many characters does 'diﬃcult' have?

Comment: Kind-of you can set locale to something `.UTF-8` and then use `mblen`.

Comment: If you need real Unicode handling, the "normal" library is [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: Counting the number of codepoints in a UTF-8 string is trivial to write yourself.  Do you have a better example?

Answer (score 3):

C++ Standard used to have various utf8 conversion routines, specified in `codecvt`. But they are deprecated since C++17. A bit of rationale can be found in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html, in particular:

> The contents of are underspecified, and will take a reasonable amount
> of work to identify and correct all of the issues. There appears to be
> a general feeling that this is not the best way to address unicode
> transcoding in the first place, and this library component should be
> retired to Annex D, along side , until a suitable replacement is
> standardized.